# How do I edit a Linux ISO on Windows using command-line?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, iso-image, bootable-media

I have a bootable ISO for a Linux product. I want to add a single file to the root of the ISO and save it the same way as the original, bootable format. The program needs to be able to run on windows command line as I plan to automate the ISO update process.
I've checked a number of options such as MagicISO and PowerISO but couldn't get them to create a new bootable ISO that would work for Linux.
I'm open to free or paid options.
Thanks for any help or tips offered.
Jack

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem and I have been looking at the alternatives. Thanks to [this answer](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/111246#111246) I found that the following works:

```
growisofs -M image_to_grow.iso -R -J files_or_dirs_to_add
```

In this case I have used the ISO image instead of the DVD device descriptor in the reference, but the command did still work, although there were a couple of warnings: there may be some options to prevent these, but I didn't investigate.
I tested by adding a single file to the root of a Linux LiveCD and the updated file could be mounted with:

```
mount -o ro,loop -t iso9660 image_to_grow.iso /mnt/tmp
```

The mounted volume seemed to contain both added file and all the original ones, and after dismounting I found that I could boot the new image in VMware: the new file was again present in the root of the CDrom. I did all this when logged on as `root`, though this may not be necessary, since physical devices are not being accessed.

[These answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174626/how-do-i-burn-a-dvd-iso-using-the-terminal) contain details of other programs which may also be adaptable to solve your problem.

I would urge you to work on copies of the original files, or at least make sure they are well backed up beforehand (ISO files usually compress quite well).

If this doesn't work for you, then the long-handed way to do what you want is to load a DVD-RAM or DVD-RW in your drive and burn the image, update it and create a new ISO image, using one of several command-line tools available in Linux.

Comment: I searched the web for a windows implementation of growisofs and found http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/tools/win32/

Comment: It is included in the standard Ubuntu distribution, so I would have expected it to be an installable option in the package manager for whatever Linux system you use. Can you use Linux for the batch processing?

Comment: I searched the web for a windows implementation of growisofs and found http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/tools/win32/ - I copied the files to a local directory and ran the command you specified above. However, it didn't seem to update the ISO as expected. I get a warning about "-rock has the same effect as -rational-rock on this platform". It's also complaining about the options for mkisofs. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found that it worked when files were added to the root directory or to a new directory with `-root`, but mkisofs crashed if I passed a directory name that already existed in the ISO to `-root`. This worked in the Linux version, however:  `growisofs -M ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64-preseed.iso -R -J -l -quiet -root preseed preseed`